# Addressing different interfaces on the same server

Tags: linux, networking, forwarding

The server is temporarily attached to four net cards.  One is the internal network, and the others go to to three different ISPs.  Two of those are NATted and the other one has a public IP.

PCs on the internal network connect to the internal IP address on eth2r, which is also the default gateway, DNS and DHCP.  However, in some cases, for example speed tests, there are interface-specific IP addresses.  On the server, `net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding=1`, so *usually* packets addressed to a different interface arrive at their destination.  I say usually because on the newly attached interface it doesn't happen.  For example, on a client in the internal network I can ping the IP address of the router attached to the external interface:

```sh
ale@pcale:/home/moz$ ping -p deadbeef 192.168.4.254
PATTERN: 0xdeadbeef
PING 192.168.4.254 (192.168.4.254) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.4.254: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=0.608 ms
...
```

On the server I see the packets like this:

```sh
574-north:share# tcpdump -vvvv -n -i any 'icmp[44]=0xde and icmp[45]=0xad and icmp[46]=0xbe and icmp[47]=0xef' 
tcpdump: data link type LINUX_SLL2
tcpdump: listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL2 (Linux cooked v2), snapshot length 262144 bytes
13:04:35.625247 eth2r In  IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 41892, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    172.25.197.111 > 192.168.4.254: ICMP echo request, id 22506, seq 49, length 64
13:04:35.625287 eth0r Out IP (tos 0x0, ttl 63, id 41892, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    192.168.4.1 > 192.168.4.254: ICMP echo request, id 22506, seq 49, length 64
13:04:35.625583 eth0r In  IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 59736, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    192.168.4.254 > 192.168.4.1: ICMP echo reply, id 22506, seq 49, length 64
13:04:35.625639 eth2r Out IP (tos 0x0, ttl 63, id 59736, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    192.168.4.254 > 172.25.197.111: ICMP echo reply, id 22506, seq 49, length 64
...
```

The client is connected to eth2r, eth0r is one of the external cards having 192.168.4.1 configured on the server and 192.168.4.245 as the remote address.  Similar behavior occurs for the interface with public IP.

However, the other NATted interface doesn't forward:

```sh
ale@pcale:/home/moz$ ping -p deadbeef 192.168.1.254
PATTERN: 0xdeadbeef
PING 192.168.1.254 (192.168.1.254) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 192.168.1.254 ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 5107ms
```

192.168.1.254 is the IP configured on eth1r.  On the server I just see the requests

```sh
13:05:25.398401 eth2r In  IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 48063, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    172.25.197.111 > 192.168.1.254: ICMP echo request, id 34888, seq 1, length 64
13:05:26.409254 eth2r In  IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 48189, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    172.25.197.111 > 192.168.1.254: ICMP echo request, id 34888, seq 2, length 64
13:05:27.432784 eth2r In  IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 48354, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    172.25.197.111 > 192.168.1.254: ICMP echo request, id 34888, seq 3, length 64
13:05:28.457115 eth2r In  IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 48520, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    172.25.197.111 > 192.168.1.254: ICMP echo request, id 34888, seq 4, length 64
13:05:29.480797 eth2r In  IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 48618, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    172.25.197.111 > 192.168.1.254: ICMP echo request, id 34888, seq 5, length 64
13:05:30.505181 eth2r In  IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 48823, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    172.25.197.111 > 192.168.1.254: ICMP echo request, id 34888, seq 6, length 64
```

This interface is the current default gateway on the server, so, just to show that the interface works, if I ping an external host it passes there.  On the client:

```sh
ale@pcale:~/tmp$ ping -p deadbeef superuser.com
PATTERN: 0xdeadbeef
PING superuser.com (151.101.193.69) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 151.101.193.69 (151.101.193.69): icmp_seq=1 ttl=58 time=2.65 ms
...
```

And on the server:

```
13:56:34.098946 eth2r In  IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 9474, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    172.25.197.111 > 151.101.193.69: ICMP echo request, id 9145, seq 1, length 64
13:56:34.098974 eth1r Out IP (tos 0x0, ttl 63, id 9474, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    192.168.1.254 > 151.101.193.69: ICMP echo request, id 9145, seq 1, length 64
13:56:34.101454 eth1r In  IP (tos 0xc, ttl 59, id 15052, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    151.101.193.69 > 192.168.1.254: ICMP echo reply, id 9145, seq 1, length 64
13:56:34.101469 eth2r Out IP (tos 0xc, ttl 58, id 15052, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    151.101.193.69 > 172.25.197.111: ICMP echo reply, id 9145, seq 1, length 64
...
```

This is Devuan chimaera (equivalent to Debian bullseye.)  Three of the cards, including the non-forwarding one, are actually on a single card with four RJ45s.

**EDIT** Adding a tentative diagram with IP numbers
[image: diagram with IP numbers]

**EDIT2** Insert eth?r in the diagram above and routing tables below (excluding ISP2)

```
$ ip route show
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth1r proto static 
172.25.197.0/24 dev eth2r proto kernel scope link src 172.25.197.1 
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth1r proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.254 
192.168.4.0/24 dev eth0r proto kernel scope link src 192.168.4.1 

$ ip route show table ISP1
default via 192.168.4.254 dev eth0r proto static 
172.25.197.0/24 dev eth2r proto static scope link 
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth1r proto static scope link src 192.168.1.254 
192.168.4.0/24 dev eth0r proto static scope link src 192.168.4.1 

$ ip route show table ISP3
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth1r proto static 
172.25.197.0/24 dev eth2r proto static scope link 
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth1r proto static scope link src 192.168.1.254 
192.168.4.0/24 dev eth0r proto static scope link src 192.168.4.1
```

**EDIT3** ip rule

```
# ip rule
0:  from all lookup local
32760:  from all oif eth1r lookup ISP3
32761:  from all iif eth1r lookup ISP3
32762:  from 192.168.1.0/24 lookup ISP3
32763:  from all oif eth0r lookup ISP1
32764:  from all iif eth0r lookup ISP1
32765:  from 192.168.4.1 lookup ISP1
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
```

Comment: Can you add your routing table (and maybe a small diagram)? On the server, are there any `net.ipv4.conf.default.`, `net.ipv4.conf.ethN.`, or `ip_forwarding` settings that may be causing your new interface to behave differently? It's hard to tell which host is which in your question, but it looks like the new interface is listening and forwarding, just not to the other internal network(s).

Comment: `sysctl -a | grep [.]forwarding` shows all 1's for IPv4, except loopback.  IPV6's were all 0, so I tried setting them to 1, but, as it could be easily anticipated, nothing changed.

Comment: What are your settings for `net.ipv4.ip_forward` and `net.ipv4.conf.*.rp_filter`?

Comment: `sysctl -a | grep [.]rp_filter` shows all 0;s, `net.ipv4.ip_foward = 1`.

Comment: The question is: *why packets are not forwarded?*  `ip rule`'s output added in EDIT3.

Comment: Can you provide either `iptables-save -c` or `nft list ruleset` (if actual nftables rules were used, rather than iptables-nft)?

Comment: Also, ISP2 is mentioned, but not documented. Are you sure that its settings if they exist never conflict?

Comment: @Ale in your working example, you ping the ISP1 address, but the non-working example is pinging the EXT3 IP `192.168.1.254`. Are you able to ping the ISP3 IP from your client (and unable to ping EXT1)?

Comment: I have a complicated iptables setting, which I thought I had carefully reviewed.  After @A.B comment, I swept all iptables rules and after that, to my surprise, pinging EXT3 works.  I don't feel like publishing the whole iptables setting, though.

Comment: Got it!  Thanks to all.  (I have to say that iptables-restore didn't bring back a working NAT.  I was right to be afraid to do that test.)

Answer (score 1):

There were a few lines, almost hidden in a landscape of a 347-line iptables script, which looked like so:

```sh
iptables -A interna_addr -m conntrack --ctorigdst 192.168.4.1 -j RETURN
iptables -A interna_addr -m conntrack --ctorigdst 192.168.0.1 -j RETURN
iptables -A interna_addr -m conntrack --ctorigdst 192.168.0.0/16 -j DROP
```

I said *almost hidden* (also) because they're written with numbers, unlike the rest of the script which uses shell variables.  They're part of a sequence of lines aimed at *bogon* filtering, which I had written several years ago after a misunderstood advice and then forgotten.

[Bogon filtering](https://www.team-cymru.com/bogon-reference-dns) is to be applied on the border of an Autonomous System, certainly not at an ISP connection.  Now I'm going to remove that scum.